# Inserting display objects into a group or table

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to add these emitter objects into a group without having to do it manually. I was going to do Emitter..i but it's not a string

```
local function createEmitter(X,Y)
local emitter = display.newEmitter( emitterParams ) 
  emitter:scale(1.5,1.3)
  emitter.isVisible = false         
  emitter.x =X
  emitter.y =Y
  return emitter
end 

emitter_1 = createEmitter()
emitter_2 = createEmitter()
emitter_3 = createEmitter()
for i=1,3 do        
  EmitGroup:insert(emitter_1)
end
```

Comment: Do you need the `emitter_#` variables for anything?

Comment: Well I'll be looping through group for a collision

Comment: That's not an answer. I assume you will be looping through the entries in the `EmitGroup`, right? Do you need those *exact* variables or can you (as I just assumed/asked) get the entries that are in the group?

Comment: Oh sorry,yea group entries
EmitGroup[i].isVisible = true

Comment: Then just use `EmitGroup:insert(createEmitter())` and loop over the entries in `EmitGroup`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding it in to group using for loop you can insert them inside the function itself.

```
local function createEmitter(X,Y)
  local emitter = display.newEmitter( emitterParams ) 
  emitter:scale(1.5,1.3)
  emitter.isVisible = false         
  emitter.x =X
  emitter.y =Y
  EmitGroup:insert(emitter) -- Added line
 return emitter
end 

emitter_1 = createEmitter()
emitter_2 = createEmitter()
emitter_3 = createEmitter()
```

-- for i=1,3 do
     -- EmitGroup:insert(emitter_1)
    --end